# How do I calculate in meters how far away I am with Latitude and longitude?

Tags: linear-algebra

To make it clearer, if I was given a longitude of 41 what would be the formula? 
 How would I work out how far I am from the Prime meridian, along the surface of the earth, in meters?

And likewise if I was given a latitude of say -61 how would I work out how far I am from the equator?

Comment: The longitude question also depends on the latitude you are at. If you're very close to the pole, it might be a matter of meters. If you're at the equator, it might be more than 1000 km. The latitude question does not, though.

Comment: The prime meridean is at longitude 0.

Answer (score 1):

At the equator or along a meridian, one degree corresponds to roughly 111 km, or one arc-minute corresponds quite well to one nautical mile (1852 m). Even these simple approximations are not 100% correct, e.g., because the earth is not a perfect sphere; but I bet they are good enough for your application.

For two points that are away from the equator but in relatively *short* distance to each other, you may use the following as as simple *approximation*:

1. Compute the north-south distance as above, i.e., one nautical mile per arc-minute in latitude difference
2. For the west-east distance, calculate one nautical mile per arc-minute in longitude difference, but multiply the result with the sine of the common (almost identical) latitude.
3. Use pythagoras to compute the "diagonal" distance from the north-south and west-east distance

Again, this approximation is not perfect, but certainly good enough for most everyday applications. In some cases, you may even want to let the elevation difference enter into the Pythagoras calculation ...

Comment: Ok so I understand that the latitude  distance in KM is ~ degrees * 111

However is there a formula that I can use to work out the distance for longitude in km/meters if both the longitude and latitude are provide in degrees?